# Style dropdown icon that toggles on click using just CSS?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am able to style the drop-down icon for the `select` box. However, I want to toggle the icon depending if the dropdown is visible or not.

- when dropdown is not visible, show icon1
- when user clicks on dropdown, show icon2
- when user closes the dropdown, show again icon1.

What I did is to use the `:focus` on `select` to manipulate the icon.

The problem is with the last step. When user clicks anywhere on the screen - or press ESC for example - to close the dropdown, the focus is still on the `select` tag, and the style is not changed back. Only until user clicks one more time, the focus is removed and everything is back to normal.

Is there way to force focus removal when dropdown is closed?

This is examined in Chrome.

https://codepen.io/igorspasic/pen/GQqKqy

p.s. javascript is welcome, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set it to blur with JavaScript. Here I've just used a `change` and `mouseout` event to remove the focus:

```js
var select = document.querySelector('#x');

function blurSelect() {
  select.blur();
}

document.onkeyup = function(e){
  if (e.keyCode === 27) {
    blurSelect()
  }
};

select.onmouseout = function() {
  blurSelect()
};
```

```css
select {
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 20px;
}

select:focus {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<select id="x">
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
</select>

<br><br><br>
Q: How to remove focus on select when dropdown is closed and turn back to blue?
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, this works only if mouse stays on top of the select. If I 1) click the select, and 2) move mouse away and 3) the click or press ESC to close the dropdown, the focus stays on select until I move the mouse. Is there a way to trigger mouseout when I close the dropdown?

Comment: remove the `change` event

Comment: I've updated my answer to factor in `esc` being pressed, and re-formatted it. I'm not aware of any way of detected when the dropdown itself is closed.

Answer (score 0):

> You can include jQuery library and add the following jQuery code in **<script>** tag.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) {
            $("#x").blur();
        }
    });
    $("#x").change( function() {
        $("#x").blur();
    });
});
```